# NSXMLParser processing complex units of information

Tags: nsxmlparser

I'm processing a response from the server using NSXMLParser successfuly.

Something like this

```
<data>
<company id="">
 <name>XXX</name>
 <latitude></latitude>
 <longitude></longitude>
</company>
<company id="">
 <name>XXX</name>
 <latitude></latitude>
 <longitude></longitude>
</company>
</data>
```

I've been using the next methods

- didStartElement:namespaceURI: ... to detect when the new company need to be parsed, then I allocate a new instance. And also, detect when an attribute starts
- foundCharacters: process the content of every attribute
- didEndElement: ... the company has been parsed completely and could be added to the internal list. And also, detect when an attribute has been processed, then set the value processed on the foundCharacters: method

Now, I also need to get the complete XML for one company, and store it in a local cache, anybody knows if there is any way using NSXMLParser to get all the content just for one company? Or maybe without using NSXMLParser. don't know.

```
<company id="">
 <name>XXX</name>
 <latitude></latitude>
 <longitude></longitude>
</company>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to re-create the XML usign the SAX methods

**parser:didStartElement:**

```
// Adding the initial TAG of the xml
accountXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<%@", elementName];
for (NSString *key in [attributeDict allKeys]){
    accountXML = [accountXML stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@=\"%@\"", key
                  , [attributeDict valueForKey:key]];
}
accountXML = [accountXML stringByAppendingString:@">\n"];
```

and

**parser:didEndElement:**

```
// Add the xml to the account and release it
accountXML = [accountXML stringByAppendingFormat:@"</%@>\n", elementName];
[account setCompleteXML:accountXML];
```